# Selecting a list to a new fragment - best design decision

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to create the following layout in landscape in Android. My question is a design question. Any advice is greatly received

[image]

This is a standard view (similar to gmail in landscape) where you select a item from a list and the details appear to the right.

My question is should I have one active for the list view and then anotehr activity for the list view/detail? Or should I programatically add the detail view and programmatically resize the list width all in one list view?

In other words
activity 1 contain list and programaticall adds detail to the layout
or  active 1 contains list and active 2 contains both list and detail and gets activated on list item click in activity 1

Are there any pros and cons (performance is the main thing) with either of these.

For portrait mode I will switch between the list and the list detials view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in terms of usability/user experience, you'd use the 1st approach for phone UI and the 2nd one for `xlarge` phones and tablets, as stated in [quality guidelines](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html) for tablet devices.

Though when in landscape, there's usually enough space to always use the second approach - but this depends of how your details layout looks. If you have a lot of small elements, use the 1st approach for phones. Otherwise, you could always use the split mode in landscape.